# message.reaction.count Discord py

Tags: discord.py, message

I'm trying to make a simple bot that would only react to messages with attachments. Then after a certain time, it would make a link to the message and send it on a moderation channel if it got 2 or more reactions.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.channel.id == 828579458167996420:
    if message.attachments or "http" in message.content:
      msgID = message.id
      await message.add_reaction("<:uut:828580756384120912>")
      await asyncio.sleep(200)
      x = int
      if message.reactions.count(x) >= 3:
        link = 'https://discord.com/channels/11223345678900/828579458167996420/' + str(msgID)
        channel = client.get_channel(892065611876823100)
        x = x - 1
        await channel.send("this post " + str(link) + "is liked " + str(x) + "times." )
```

the bot reacts to the messages i want, but it doesn't post anything in the moderation channel

I'm a beginner, sry for the messy codes :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not getting any kinds of errors, the issue lays right here, the if statement never gets triggered:

```py
x = int
if message.reactions.count(x) >= 3:
```

`message.reactions` will return a list, your statement would count how many times `x` is in that list (which is always zero).
What you wanna do instead is just to get the total length of that list, like this:

```py
if len(message.reactions) >= 3:
```

Also other small improvement tip: You can get the URL of a message with `message.jump_url`

EDIT:

Sorry, what you actually need to do to get the reaction count is to either search the emoji you want to count, or the shortcut would be to just get the first reaction in that list, since your bot *should* be the first to react to that message anyways:

```py
#this will return a list of reactions that match the emoji you want
emoji = [x for x in message.reactions if str(x.emoji) == ''] #replace the emoji with the one you want
print(emoji[0].count) #counts the first (and only) emoji in the new list
```

"Shortcut" version, just gets the first reaction count:

```py
print(message.reactions[0].count)
```

Comment: omg message.jump_url is such an improvement! unfortunately i still have a problem with the script, as the len(message.reaction) only gives the number of different emojies. What i need is the number of people reacting with the same emojie the bot added

Comment: Ah yes sorry that is entirely my fault for not understanding your question properly, I have edited my answer above. Hope this helps!

Comment: if message.reactions[0].count worked perfectly, thx